# Selenium 4 grid hub in standalone server (Dockerized container hub) and Chrome node pods in Cloud

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, openshift, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

Selenium grid question (scenario: hub in standalone server and Chrome node pods in cloud) - Details: I have a selenium 4 grid hub running in docker container in Linux server and docker published to port 4444 to make it available in localhost:4444 (or 0.0.0.0:4444).
For user access, I expose 0.0.0.0:4444 to network machines using FastAPI routing options.
Also, i wanted to register Node Pods from network machines or some other cloud machines.
Note: Selenium-server-4.5.0.jar or higher versions are used in implementation.
Is this architecture supported by current selenium 4 grid implementation.